# Javascript - Detect window.location in iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I have an Iframe and I want a javascript function to run, If the iframe changes location with a window.location / window.open

I tried this, but its not working :/

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/" onload="myFunction()" id="iframe">   </iframe>
<p>If this iframe ^^^^ changes location on a window.location/ window.open, I want the alert to go off</p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
alert(document.getElementById('iframe').src)
}
</script>
```

```js
function myFunction() {
alert(document.getElementById('iframe').src)
}
```

```html
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/" onload="myFunction()" id="iframe"></iframe>
<p>If this iframe ^^^^ changes location on a window.location/ window.open, I want the alert to go off</p>
```

Comment: You can poll it or bind to unload, but if it is cross domain, there is really nothing you can do

Comment: If I changed the iframe to an object, would it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can access an iframe's current URL with `.documentWindow.location.href` in Firefox or `.contentDocument.location.href` in Chrome. With `.src` you will always get the last *programmatically* changed URL, either with the `src` HTML attribute or via JavaScript.

Having said all that, you cannot access anything below `documentWindow` or `contentDocument` if the domain of the URL in the iframe differs from the domain of the website executing the JavaScript code.

That is for normal browsers. You can give [Electron](https://electron.atom.io) a try if you really need to do it. Basically, with electron you can build your own browser with no security restrictions. But only you will use it, not the visitors of your website, and it is not straightforward.